# Getting Aptana setup with Nokia WRT plugin

Tags: aptana, s60, nokia-wrt

I've just installed Aptana and gone through the process of creating the default RSS Reader following the wizard. I changed the name and the url but nothing else.

It works fine in the preview in Aptana.

Two problems:

i). When I try to setup the device to deploy to, pressing the Search button in Window->preferences->Web Runtime->Deployment exits quickly without finding my device.

So, I dragged the widget onto my N82 (SW version 20.0.062) using a wired connection, it installed ok. However:

ii). When the widget attempts to connect it displays 'Updating feed' briefly but then exits back to the applications menu really quickly.

Any ideas for either of the issues? Particularly #2 and how best can I debug the issue if it happens in future?

Comment: Note - I asked this same question on the official Aptana forums a week ago http://forums.aptana.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=9247 but my question has only had 10 views (and at least 3 of those were me!). Hopefully StackOverflow has more success.

Comment: Seems quiet here too... You could try Forum Nokia's WRT forums at http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=160 . If you do get an answer in some other place, please post it here too.

Answer (score 1):

With #2 your best bet is to just add alert-function calls in the code path as breakpoints as on-device debugging in S60 devices is pretty non-existant.

One possible problem is that there's been problems with asynchronous xmlhttp-requests in some versions of the Nokia browser. Changing the request to synchronous would be the first thing I'd try. Obviously that sucks, because the UI freezes for the duration of the xmlhttp request, but those are the cards we've been dealt.

Also, you did remember to explicitly allow network connections in the info.plist -file of the widget, right? Here's the key/value-pair that'll do the trick:

```
<key>AllowNetworkAccess</key>
<true/>
```